# Perl script running in background of web page

Tags: php, perl, background

I have a web page which uses php exec() to run a perl script which writes to a file. The problem is, the perl script takes a long time to execute, and I would like to start showing the results on the webpage before it finally returns. I currently have exec() displaying the content of the file it writes to in a div which gets reloaded every 3 seconds.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the page to start loading before the perl script finishes. Does anyone have an idea on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your perlscript from a different php-file in an iframe. This way it will execute the script but you do not need to wait for it to succeed. If the perlscript prints to your file before it is ready, you even could read those lines in your mainpage and show first results.

Comment: thank you for this idea! I actually created another perl script which ran the other one in the background and returned !

Answer (score 0):

See Randal's definitive article on the topic: [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html). You'll need to adapt the Perl CGI script he uses to watch the `traceroute` output and do something similar using PHP. The essential idea is:

> the browser hits the form, and the user fills out that form; the browser submits the form, and after verifying good infomation, the response forks to run the task, and redirects the browser back with a session key; the forked process runs the task, taking output as it arrives and updates a cache value, flagging when it is complete; the CGI script pulls from the cache, and displays it, sending a refresh as long as the data is not complete.

Comment: @Quentin Unless this is an automated script, your pouncing is completely uncalled for.

Comment: How about your write a real answer before clicking "Post your answer" instead of writing a link only answer, posting it, and then editing it?

Answer (score -1):

How can you close out the page's body tag and send it if you don't have all the content?

You need to rearchitect it as an asynchronout load, where the page serves up javascript that calls a server url that returns partial results, appends that to the DOM, and continues calling the server url to get more partial results.

Comment: You don't need to close out the page's body tag before you start sending it. Buffering the data before sending it just means you can include a `Content-Length` header and allow for partial requests.

Comment: The HTML content (</body>) has nothing to do with the transport mechanism (HTTP, which has headers). Once the server has sent the content it can't go back and tell the client 'welp I sent the wrong content, here, discard what I sent before and use this instead.'

Comment: Actually, you can (by using [multipart/x-mixed-replace](http://oreilly.com/openbook/cgi/ch06_06.html) content), but you don't need to since you can say "Here is some of the document, here is some more, and some more, and some more". Browsers don't wait for the body end tag to be received from the server before they start rendering the document.

Comment: Is that supported by IE now? And while I'm aware some browsers do partial rendering, I wasn't aware that it was something that could be relied on for cross-platform compatibility, and that it led to fun issues depending on the complexity of the partial content.